# How to run batch file and leave it open to continue running (2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

My current code for opening up a batch file is as follows:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/cgminer-3.7.2-windows/mining.bat")
```

The only problem is that 'mining.bat' does not have a specified end, and will run for as long as possible. When I run the code, the batch file is opened, but it then closes after a few seconds. How can I get it to open the batch file, and then leave it alone and let it keep running?

Comment: Use `call` instead of `Popen`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487231/how-to-start-a-batch-file-from-within-a-python-script-and-detach-from-it