# How to start a batch file from within a python script and detach from it

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a python script that needs to start a `.bat` file. The `.bat` file runs indefinitely, and, ideally, never returns.

There's no problem running a foreign executable or `.bat` from within a python script, but all the implementations I've found run it as a child and wait for it to return.

Can I run an external script and detach from it, allowing it to run merrily, and have the python script continue to run?

**Edit: ** using `Popen` runs the batch file in the same command prompt window - as the batch file never returns, the python app us unable to continue running. Is there a way to run a batch file in a new command prompt window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["mybatchfile.bat"])
```

This starts the batch file and will not wait for to complete. If you want to verify that process is created, you can run:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["mybatchfile.bat"])
if p.pid > 0:
   print "Process created with PID:", p.pid
```

Comment: From the Python Documentation: `On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.`